# How to catch this error? [C++]

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm trying to catch dividing by zero attempt:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int a = 5;
try
{
int b = a / 0;
}
catch(const exception& e)
{
    cerr << e.what();
}
catch(...)
{
    cerr << "Unknown error.";
}
    cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

and basically it doesn't work. Any advice why?
Thank you.
P.S. 
Any chance that in the future code can be placed between [code][/code] tags instead of four spaces?

Comment: Re your PS: Markdown is not BBCode or whatever uses [code]. You can paste your code into the editor, highlight it and then Ctrl+K to automatically indent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide by zero does not raise any exceptions in Standard C++, instead it gives you undefined behaviour. Typically, if you want to raise an exception you need to do it yourself:

```
int divide( int a, int b ) {
   if ( b == 0 ) {
      throw DivideByZero;    // or whatever
   }
   return a / b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys.
P.S. Is there any reason why comment has to be at least 15 char long?

Comment: Personally I'd make that a template, and call it checked_divide.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to check if the divisor equals 0.

C++ doesn't check divide-by-zero. A brief discussion can be found [here](http://www.jdl.co.uk/briefings/divByZeroInCpp.html).

Comment: interesting though, atch reports that he got no exception thrown, which is not concurrent with your link... hmm

Comment: the discussion says that the hardware *might* throw exception, not that it definitely throws one. The approach shows how to test this.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be currently writing code for Windows (evidence: `_tmain` and `_TCHAR` are not portable C++).

If you would like a solution which only works on Windows, then you can use so-called "structured exception handling" (SEH):

- Enable structured exceptions by compiling with /EHa: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx
- Use `__try`, `__except` and an exception filter to only catch EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363082.aspx

However, this is a MS-only feature. If you rely on an exception being thrown to deal with this error, then it will take considerable effort to change your code later if you want it to work on other platforms.

It's better to write your code with an awareness of when the divisor might be 0 (just as when you do mathematics, and divide by a quantity, you must consider whether it might be 0). Neil's approach is a good low-impact solution for this: you can use his `divide` function whenever you aren't sure.